# How to compile a C program with a personal library that includes threads

Tags: c, gcc, pthreads, header-files, gnome-terminal

I created a library for my C programs and this includes threads. I usually work with Code::Blocks and I never had  problems, but now I need to compile programs directly from terminal. I saw that I need to write `-lpthread` but also my library name (its name is my_lib.h).  I tried to compile first the library with `gcc my_lib.c -c` and this works; after, I tried this `gcc main.c my_lib.h -o main -lpthread`, but this doesn't work.

So what is the correctly sintax to compile this program that uses my_lib.h?

Comment: Never pass .h files as arguments to the compiler. "Doesn't work" is a useless statement. Did your computer explode, or did it turn into a potato? Those are two very different modes of failure.

Comment: the second step is called linking and it expects my_lib.o instead of my_lib.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `my_lib.c` is just a module (object file) rather than shared library.

The compiling consists of two parts - compiling into object files and then linking:

```
# compiling (note the -c)
gcc -c my_lib.c
gcc -c main.c
# linking (no -c, just specify target with -o)
gcc -o main main.o my_lib.o -lpthread
```

Header files are never compiled (explicitly), they are just included from the `.c` files and therefore never produce `.o` file.